# Is it ok to embed flash games on a site with ads?

Tags: copyright, flash

I have a new game website, and I decided I wanted to make some money off of it. The only problem is I don't know if it's OK to make money off of a game I didn't make without permission. I've looked all over Google, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Sorry but the question is too specific, unclear and a little board. Answers would likely be opinionated rather than fact.  You should always ask permission from the publisher, or seek proper legal advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the entire terms and conditions attached to the flash game in question to make sure you have full legal rights to make money off of it.

If the game was something you downloaded then uploaded to a server, then look for a file named readme or license or even readme.txt or license.txt to see what the legal rules are with that game.

Also check out the terms and conditions on the website where you got the game from to make sure you understand everything.

If the game has a copyright label to it, you must contact the name of the company or individual that has setup the copyright for permission to monetize it.

If you do not do all of these things, then chances are you may have your advertising account suspended at best, and/or be up for legal charges and/or end up in jail for making money off of someone else's hard work behind their back.